# Perfect codes and the Golay codes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, coding-theory

I've been working on exercises from various textbooks to get a better understading about perfect codes. There is a theorem that states:

> **Theorem:** The only nontrivial perfect multiple error-correcting codes that have the same length, number of codewords, and minimum distance are either the $[23, 12, 7]$ binary Golay code or the $[11, 6, 5]$ ternary Golay code.

In order to help the reader prove this theorem, the book breaks the theorem into 4 parts. They are as follows:

> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an $[n, k, 7]$ perfect binary code:
>
> (1) Using the Sphere Packing Bound, show that
>   $$(n+1)[(n+1)^2 - 3(n+1) + 8] = 3 \cdot 2^{n - k + 1}.$$
>   (2) Show that $n+1$ is either $2^b$ or $3 \cdot 2^b$, where in either case, $b \leq n - k + 1.$
>
> (3) Show that $b < 4$.
>
> (4) Show that $n = 23$ or $n = 7$.

I am able to show (1), but I am having difficulty showing (2) - (4). I have a feeling that there is some number theory involved with prime numbers, but I'm not seeing it. Furthermore, since this is an $[n, k, 7]$ code, I know that $n \geq 7$

I would love to finish the proof to this theorem since it's stated in many textbooks without proof. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**
With the help of Gerry from the comments, (2) and (4) work out easily. For (2), it follows from (1) that $(n+1) | 3 \cdot 2^{n - k + 1}$. Therefore, $(n+1)$ must be of the form $2^b$ or $3 \cdot 2^b$, and since these powers of 2 cannot be bigger than the power of 2 on the right hand side, it follows that $b \leq n - k + 1$. For (4), it follows from (3), and the fact that $n \geq 7$ that $n = 7, 11,$  or $23$. If we plug these values into (1) it follows that: $n = 7 \Rightarrow 2^k = 2 \Rightarrow k = 1$, $n = 11 \Rightarrow 2^k = 8.827\ldots, $ $n = 23 \Rightarrow 2^k = 4096 \Rightarrow k = 12$. Therefore, $n = 7$ or $n = 23$.

Any help with (3) be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: (2) is not hard --- $n+1$ divides the right side of the equation in (1), and the right side is 3 times a power of 2, so $n+1$ must be a power of 2 or 3 times a power of 2, and the power of 2 can't be any bigger than what's on the right side.

Comment: (4) shouldn't be hard --- if $b\lt4$, then $b$ is 0, 1, 2, or 3, so $n+1$ is 1, 2, 4, 8, or 3, 6, 12, 24. Knowing $n\ge7$ rules out all but 8, 12, and 24. If $n+1=12$, you should be able to calculate the left side of (1) and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you Gerry! I had a hunch that that's how (2) was going to work out. I should be able to do something with (4) after your comment. All that is left is (3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see if this works for (3). If $b\ge4$, then $(n+1)^2-3(n+1)+8$ is divisible by $2^3$ but not by any higher power of 2. On the other hand, it's at least $16^2-(3)(16)+8=216$ so when you divide it by 8 you get an odd number that's at least 27. But the right side of (1) isn't divisible by any odd number exceeding 3, contradiction.